# Object literals in javascript can only be defined within the window object?

Tags: javascript

Can object literals be defined within any function declaration or only within the window object?

```
function declaration()
{
    var objectLiteral = {
        property1: "test1",
        method1: function() {
            return "testMethod"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WTH do you mean by "*within the window object*"? And yes, your function declaration obviously works, as you can see by trying it out.

Comment: @Bergi the *window* object is synonymous with the global space (at least in the context of a browser *window*)

Comment: thanks Jordan for clarifying my meaning of the window object

Comment: @JordanForeman: Yes, the window object represents the global scope, but still - an object literal is a *syntactic device*, and has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: @Bergi right...this question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes. An object literal can be defined in any javascript function.

Comment: @Awal Garg, even if I would have tried it out myself, not understanding the scope would have lead to another question, so asking here really helped me understanding the concept better..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object literals can be defined anywhere - but they are subject to JavaScript's scoping.

JavaScript scopes contextually - meaning anything you declare within a scope is accessible only within that scope.

The interesting thing about JS is that functions are *first class citizens*, meaning that functions have their own context just like an object or the global (window object) space. Essentially meaning you can declare functions within other functions.

Anything you define within one context is available to any child contexts that you create. Here is an example:

```
var x = {count: 0};
function doSomething() {
    console.log(x.count); // 0

    var y = {name: "bologna"};

    function printY() {
        console.log(y.name); // "bologna"

        var z = 1000;
    }

    console.log(z); // undefined
}
console.log(y); // undefined
```

This is very simplified, and scoping can get pretty complex in JS. For a more in-depth look at how JavaScript manages scoping, check out [this article](http://jordanforeman.com/understanding-javascript/) I wrote on the subject, or this excellent [Sitepoint Article](http://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/)

Comment: Downvoted - you'll need more than a link and a sentence to explain your answer.

Comment: Link only answers are not good answers. Please use this space to put all relevant information. Links are good citation, but not good answer material.

Comment: How would I access the property of an object literal within a user-defined function declaration?

Comment: That's fair. I'll edit the answer to be more descriptive

Comment: Just access it as always: `objectLiteral.property1`. You only need to consider the scope of the `objectLiteral` variable.

Comment: Now I get it after understanding the scope. The object literal is private within the function declaration and can not be access outside of the function declaration, right?

Comment: Effectively. I wouldn't use the term private, because that's a different paradigm entirely - but yes, the ultimate effect is very similar.

Comment: Thanks Jordan for clearing up my understanding. I get what you're saying but your example should have used an object literal inside the function declaration.